# Trying to do "empty" string checks and I cannot figure it out

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a automated file modifying script for some reason and I am stuck on something..

I have source code below:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync("./premaplist.txt");
str = str.toString().split("\n");
var result = "";
str.forEach(s => {
    var addstr = s;
    if(!s.includes("[")) {
        if(s.replace(/[.YBPOKGR#]/g, "") == s)return;
        addstr = "##########";
    }
    result += addstr+'\n';
})
// fs.writeFileSync("./premaplist.txt", result);
console.log(result);
```

So, the result I expect is let empty string AND string that includes `[` alone and change others to `##########`, but it replaces a empty string as `##########` too.

Is the text file being special? or am I doing it wrong or missing something?

Input:

```
[image#1]
.....B....
..BB..BBB.
.BBBBBBB.B
BBBBBBBBB.
##########

[image#2]
GGGG......
GGGGGG....
GGGGGGG...
GGGGGGG...
GGGGGGGG..
GGGGGGGG..
GGGGGGGG..
GGGGGGGGG.
GGGGGGGGG.

[image#3]
.........K
```

(there are actually thousands of these)

Expected output:

```
[image#1]
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########

[image#2]
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########

[image#3]
##########
```

Actual output:

```
[image#1]
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
[image#2]
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
##########
[image#3]
##########
```

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. Please add to your question (and clearly label) the **input** (ideally something that causes all code paths to be executed at least once), the **expected output** and the **actual output**.

Comment: @CherryDT I have edited my question, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output you are getting because you are doing `return` when its empty string therefore nothing gets added to result when its empty string

Try doing like this

```
const fs = require('fs');
var str = fs.readFileSync("./premaplist.txt");
str = str.toString().split("\n");
var result = "";
str.forEach(s => {
    var addstr = s;
    if(!s.includes("[")) {
        addstr = s.replace(/[.YBPOKGR#]/g, "") == s ?"":"##########"
    }
    result += addstr+'\n';
})
// fs.writeFileSync("./premaplist.txt", result);
console.log(result);
```

Live here [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/CarpalSourBots#index.js)